# d3js: How to select only x number of values from data

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js

I have some data in the format given below:

```
var data = [
  {name: "A", rank: 0, c: 92}, 
  {name: "B", rank: 45, c: 99},
  {name: "C", rank: 89, c: 89},
  {name: "D", rank: 23, c: 99},
  {name: "E", rank: 56, c: 98}
];
```

I want to find a subset of this data like say only 3 values. I am not sure how to do this is d3js. The solutions I found were mainly based on the property of data like:

```
data = data.filter(function(d){return +d.rank < 10});
```

But this gives me all data points with rank < 10 but I want to limit the "size" of data (number of data points) based on some user input.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

May be like this using [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) + [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice):

```js
var data = [
  {name: "A", rank: 0, c: 92},

  {name: "B", rank: 45, c: 99},

  {name: "C", rank: 89, c: 89},

  {name: "D", rank: 23, c: 99},

  {name: "E", rank: 56, c: 98}
];
var size = 3; //user input size that is needed
var result = data.filter(function(d) {return (+d.rank > 10)}).slice(0,size)
console.log(result)
```